# Multiple images gallery after a single preview HTML / CSS /JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

I want to create a gallery of multiple images, from a single "preview". I'll explain better. Let's say I have 3 different images which are 3 different products. By clicking on each of these, I would like to open a gallery (different for each preview) of x images for each single product.
I tried to create it using [LIGHTBOX by Lokesh Dhakar](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options), but I can only have one image for each single preview and the gallery is only one.
I have tried several attempts, but I can't get any better
Here is my code, hope someone has some ideas

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IMAGE GALLERY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Image Gallery Design</h1>

    <div class="gallery">
    <a href="IMAGE1.png" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Product1"><img src="PREVIEW1.png"></a>
    <a href="IMAGE2.png" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Product2"><img src="PREVIEW2.png"></a>
    <a href="IMAGE3.png" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Product3"><img src="PREVIEW3.png"></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1{
    text-align: ceter;
    color: forestgreen;
    margin: 30px 0 50px;
}

.gallery img{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 1s;
}
.gallery img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Hide the other `<a>` elements of the same set** using a CSS Utility class like `u-none` that does `display: none;`
- Use `<img>` only for the first set thumbnail

```js
lightbox.option({
  resizeDuration: 200,
  wrapAround: true
});
```

```css
.u-none {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/f0b&text=A1" data-lightbox="set_1">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/f0b&text=A1">
</a>
<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/bf0&text=A2" class="u-none" data-lightbox="set_1"></a>
<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/0bf&text=A3" class="u-none" data-lightbox="set_1"></a>
<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/b0f&text=A4" class="u-none" data-lightbox="set_1"></a>

<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/f0b&text=B1" data-lightbox="set_2">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/0bf&text=B1">
</a>
<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/0bf&text=B2" class="u-none" data-lightbox="set_2"></a>
<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/bf0&text=B3" class="u-none" data-lightbox="set_2"></a>
<a href="https://placehold.it/500x500/0fb&text=B4" class="u-none" data-lightbox="set_2"></a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

or wrap all the *hidden* set images inside a common parent `<div>` with that `u-none` class .